# How to perform differently from different segues?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a `AController` with 2 segues connected to `BController`.

In `AController` I wrote this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FirstSegue"{
        // do something 
    }
    if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue"{
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Then come to `BController`, I am looking for this:

```
if AController.segue.identifer == "FirstSegue"{
    // do something
}

if AController.segue.identifer == "SecondSegue"{
    // do something
}
```

### What should I do?

Here is the storyboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2nkZ.png)

Comment: What kind of segues are you trying to make?

Comment: Send your storyborad then i give you some suggestion ..

Comment: what do you want, to send data from AController to BController

Comment: @KSigWyatt I'm trying to present two segues as modally, One for add something new, the other is to edit some existing info

Comment: @AnuradhS Exactly. Actually I also need to change the appearance based on segues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Mr.UB's answer you could also create a variable which stores the string value of the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FirstSegue"{
        let viewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! BController 
        viewController.sourceSegue = "FirstSegue"
    }
    if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue"{
        let viewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! BController 
        viewController.sourceSegue = "SecondSegue"
    }
}
```

So you could do something like this (in BController), which is closer to what you originally wanted:

```
var sourceSegue: String!

if sourceSegue == "FirstSegue"{
    // do something
} else if sourceSegue == "SecondSegue"{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a bool variable in BController

```
var isFromA:Bool!
```

In AController:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FirstSegue"{
        let vc = segue!.destinationViewController as! BController 
        vc.isFromA = true
    }
    if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue"{
        let vc = segue!.destinationViewController as! BController 
        vc.isFromA = false
    }
 }
```

In BController:

```
if isFromA == true{
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `as! BController` becuase the destination view controller is BController?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is set a public BOOL property in View controller B

```
@interface ViewControllerB
@property(nonatomic) BOOL isFirst;
@end
```

in prepare for segue of ViewControllerA you can access the destination viewcontroller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"FirstSegue"]){
        ViewControllerB * objVC = (ViewControllerB*)[segue destinationViewController];
        objVc.isFirst = TRUE;
    }

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SecondSegue"]){
        ViewControllerB * objVC = (ViewControllerB*)[segue destinationViewController];
        objVc.isFirst = FALSE;
    } 
}
```

then in viewDidLoad of ViewControllerB you can perform different option based on property isFirst,

```
if(self.isFirst == TRUE){
//Perform First Segue functions
}else{
//Perform Second Segue Actions
}
```